# Command to install app from phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, ssh, bash

I'd like to SSH into my phone, download an APK, and install it remotely. Is there a command available on the phone that would allow me to do this?

EG:

```
wget localhost/file.apk 
android_install file.apk
```

Need to automate an install, as I just accidentally wiped my SD card and everything on it. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In adb shell or terminal emulator (and most likely over SSH) you can use the `pm` utility to install apps.  The command is:

> pm install /sdcard/app1.apk

The following are the switches of `pm`:

```
usage: pm [list|path|install|uninstall]
       pm list packages [-f] [-d] [-e] [-u] [FILTER]
       pm list permission-groups
       pm list permissions [-g] [-f] [-d] [-u] [GROUP]
       pm list instrumentation [-f] [TARGET-PACKAGE]
       pm list features
       pm list libraries
       pm path PACKAGE
       pm install [-l] [-r] [-t] [-i INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME] [-s] [-f] PATH
       pm uninstall [-k] PACKAGE
       pm clear PACKAGE
       pm enable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm disable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm setInstallLocation [0/auto] [1/internal] [2/external]

The list packages command prints all packages, optionally only
those whose package name contains the text in FILTER.  Options:
  -f: see their associated file.
  -d: filter to include disbled packages.
  -e: filter to include enabled packages.
  -u: also include uninstalled packages.

The list permission-groups command prints all known
permission groups.

The list permissions command prints all known
permissions, optionally only those in GROUP.  Options:
  -g: organize by group.
  -f: print all information.
  -s: short summary.
  -d: only list dangerous permissions.
  -u: list only the permissions users will see.

The list instrumentation command prints all instrumentations,
or only those that target a specified package.  Options:
  -f: see their associated file.

The list features command prints all features of the system.

The path command prints the path to the .apk of a package.

The install command installs a package to the system.  Options:
  -l: install the package with FORWARD_LOCK.
  -r: reinstall an exisiting app, keeping its data.
  -t: allow test .apks to be installed.
  -i: specify the installer package name.
  -s: install package on sdcard.
  -f: install package on internal flash.

The uninstall command removes a package from the system. Options:
  -k: keep the data and cache directories around.
after the package removal.

The clear command deletes all data associated with a package.

The enable and disable commands change the enabled state of
a given package or component (written as "package/class").

The getInstallLocation command gets the current install location
  0 [auto]: Let system decide the best location
  1 [internal]: Install on internal device storage
  2 [external]: Install on external media

The setInstallLocation command changes the default install location
  0 [auto]: Let system decide the best location
  1 [internal]: Install on internal device storage
  2 [external]: Install on external media
```

For example, you can force the app to install directly to the external storage (Froyo/Gingerbread style.)

P.S. The `wget` utility should be available via BusyBox on CM7.  If not, you can always install it via [Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=stericson.busybox).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. `pm` does exist at `/system/bin/pm`, but unfortunately over SSH (even as root) it doesn't do anything. Running any `pm` command produces no output. Is there something I'm doing wrong? It does work in terminal emulator, just not over SSH for some reason :(

Comment: I've had PM work as root from adb in CM6; beyond that I am unsure.

Comment: May I ask what is the reason you prefer SSH over ADB shell?

Comment: @Chahk: `adb` only works via the USB cable, doesn't it? And SSH can be over a wireless network. Also, `ssh` is there everywhere, but `adb` has to be installed.

Comment: Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: runInstallCreate from pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 11; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you plug your phone into a pc with the sdk (or at least adb) installed and in debugging mode. After this, write a script that goes through your apps and installs them via adb, e.g. `adb install x:\path\to\app1.apk`.

Comment: There's no native utility on the phone to do this?

Comment: No, since most apps just copy their .apk file to /data/app. You could try copying all your apks there and then rebooting (note that this needs root, but I assume from the cyanogenmod tag that you're rooted).

Comment: Now _that_ is something I can do over SSH, `cp * /data/app && reboot`

Comment: note that the cp command is not available in stock Android (i.e. non-custom ROM), so if you're not using Cyanogen you may need to (ab)use the `cat` command.

Comment: Actually, on the phone there is such a command.  `pm install /sdcard/app1.apk` will do the same thing as `adb install` and can be executed in adb shell, terminal emulator, and most likely over SSH.  Take a look at the output of `pm` for more options. There is even a switch to force the app to install directly to external storage (Gingerbread style).

Answer (score 2):

I am using the same method and yes SSH is great! But it seems when you SSH to Android it gets a different shell than sh so if you put sh in front of the command it should work.

Here's an example: `sh /system/bin/pm install app1.apk`